# Jetpack compose remove default Text padding

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

How to remove the default `Text` padding.

[image]

I went through this article: https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/fixing-font-padding-in-compose-text-768cd232425b

But, couldn't achieve the desired look.

```
androidx-compose-bom = "2023.10.01"
```

Font used: `Cairo`

Answer (score 0):

```
platformStyle = PlatformTextStyle(
            includeFontPadding = false )
```

[Refrence](https://www.google.com/search?q=Jetpack%20compose%20remove%20default%20Text%20padding&oq=Jetpack%20compose%20remove%20default%20Text%20padding&gs_lcrp=EgZjaHJvbWUyBggAEEUYOTIGCAEQRRg80gEHNjgyajBqMagCALACAA&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)